# 'write' is an ambiguous tag

Tags: discussion, ambiguous-tags

Stack Overflow has 638 questions tagged [write](/questions/tagged/write).

The 'related tags' gives a clue to the various areas where this tag is applied:

- [file](/questions/tagged/file) x 188
- [read](/questions/tagged/read) x 161
- [php](/questions/tagged/php) x 76
- [java](/questions/tagged/java) x 70
- [python](/questions/tagged/python) x 63
- [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) x 58
- [c](/questions/tagged/c) x 53
- [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) x 48
- [android](/questions/tagged/android) x 43
- [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) x 31
- [iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone) x 26
- [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) x 25
- [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) x 21
- [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) x 16
- [binary](/questions/tagged/binary) x 16
- [file-io](/questions/tagged/file-io) x 15
- [sockets](/questions/tagged/sockets) x 15
- [arrays](/questions/tagged/arrays) x 14
- [io](/questions/tagged/io) x 14
- [text](/questions/tagged/text) x 14
- [html](/questions/tagged/html) x 13
- [permissions](/questions/tagged/permissions) x 13
- [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c) x 12
- [unix](/questions/tagged/unix) x 12
- [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) x 11

It seems that nearly everything involves writing (or reading, or files, or io, or file-io, or text...which are equally useful).

In my opinion, this tag should be replaced with language-specific tags or burninated.

Comment: Tag ambiguity is not necessarily a problem per se.  Unless the tag fails to categorize the question in any way, it could still be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree. I think [write](/questions/tagged/write) is an acceptable tag. It helps refine questions which are specifically about writing some data (to a file or device) rather than reading data. Most questions on Stack Overflow also have a language tag, but that's no reason to ban tags other than language tags.

Yes, I'm hard-pressed to come up with a question that should be tagged only [write](/questions/tagged/write), but the same goes for, say [php](/questions/tagged/php). Almost every question should have some meaningful tag beyond the programming language, indicating what topic is broached (data structure, specific library, algorithm, …).

Comment: Hm.  I'm still not certain that there are any use cases where someone would want to refine a search by the word 'write', but I'm definitely thinking about this.